# When to stop a backsplash?

Tags: kitchens, remodeling, backsplash

We have a kitchen with a U shaped with a peninsula that divides the kitchen and the living room/dining room. If the end of the peninsula is against a black wall, how far up the wall do we stop the backsplash? I'm also assuming the backsplash will be stopped at the end of the counter top so it doesn't go into the dining room as well, right?

Hopefully I've given enough details to picture this.

Comment: You stop it where it aesthetically looks good to stop it at. It's purely a subjective answer.

Comment: A picture would help us picture what you're describing.

Comment: Backsplashes typically cover the area between the top of the countertop, and the bottom of the cabinets. If there are cabinets on the wall, use the bottom of the cabinets as a guide and carry that height across the entire wall (to the end of the counter).

Comment: -1 because this is getting close to decorating advice.

Comment: @BMitch Is this not the right place to ask this question? "Home Improvement" = broad term in my opinion

Comment: You have the right topic, but decorating advice is subjective. Subjective questions don't work well on SE because there's no specific right or wrong answer, only varying opinions. See the [faq] for more details on what's a good vs bad question.

Comment: @andrewliu The problem with this question is not that it's off topic, it's that it's subjective and cannot be answered definitively.  You may be able to reword the question to make it fit better into the SE question and answer format, but as it stands now the question does not have a *correct* answer.

Comment: The fact that it's subjective is quite a useful answer!  The asker may have wondered if there was a code or a standard or even a rule-of-thumb.

Comment: In my kitchen the upper cabinet ends about 45 cm before the countertops, so there is blank wall above that section of counter top. I chose to end my backsplash in line with the upper cabinet, rather than the end of the counter and I am happy with the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: from countertop to cabinet]

As the rest have said, its purely aesthetic. On this side of the kitchen, we took the backsplash all the way to the underside of the top cabinets to fill in the space. Using different types of tile, we made a pattern that we continued on the opposite wall

[image: no uppers]

On this side of the kitchen that doesn't have upper cabinets, we stopped it at the top marble bar. The beige field tiles make up about 1 foot in height, with another 6 inches (ish) with the detail tile.

You can really do anything you'd like. There are many examples out there of styles and things you can do.

Answer (score 1):

A backsplash is there to be aesthetically pleasing and to provide an easy to clean and durable surface behind food preparation surfaces. It needs to go far up enough to catch the majority of splashes, say a couple of feet up, however past that is all a question of style. Some would say that it should stop at a couple of feet high and extend to the ends of the countertops, however I've seen splashbacks go up most of the way (or all the way) to the ceiling and extend way past the countertops. Partly it depends on what kind of money you want to spend: the more splashback you put in the more it will cost.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This helped me get a feel as what I should do